# Given a congruence equation ax = b (mod n), how can I prove this GCD?

Tags: number-theory

I am given the equation $ax = b (mod$ $n)$ and that $d = (a,n)$. Suppose that $x_o$ is a solution to the equation.

I need to prove that d is the greatest common divisor of not only a and n, but b as well. How can I show that it's the GCD of all three of them?

Comment: Hint: First show (or recall) that if there is a solution, then $d$ must divide $b$.

Comment: That's actually a theorem with proof directly out of my book. I can show that one piece of cake. I just don't know how I can attach that proof to the other stuff.

Comment: $d$ is the biggest integer that divides $a$ and $n$. If furthermore $d$ divides $b$, then $d$ is the biggest integer that divides all of $a$, $b$, and $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First show (or recall) that if the congruence has a solution, then $d$ must divide $b$.

Comment: That's actually a theorem with proof directly out of my book. I can show that one piece of cake. I just don't know how I can attach that proof to the other stuff.

Comment: @h527b5tv986b There are various ways, e.g. using Euclid's algorithm, or direct application of the definition of the gcd in terms of divisibility laws - see my answer.

Comment: @h527b5tv986b:  After the theorem referred to in the answer, it's all over. Since the congruence has a solution, $d$ divides    $b$, so $d$ divides all of $a$, $n$, and $b$. Thus $d$ is a common divisor of $a$, $n$, and $b$. And it is the *greatest* common divisor, since already nothing $\gt d$ divides both $a$ and $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ \gcd(a,n,b) = \gcd(\color{#c00}a,n,\!\!\!\overbrace{\color{#c00}ax_a\!+ny}^{\large \equiv\ ny\pmod{\!\color{#c00}a}}\!\!\!) = \gcd(a.\color{#0a0}n,\color{#0a0}ny) = \gcd(a,n)\ $ by Euclid's algorithm.

**Or** directly: $\,d\mid a,n\iff d\mid a,n,\,ax_a\!+ny\,$ so $\ a,n\,$ and $\,a,n,\,ax_a\!+ny\,$ have the same set $\,S$ of *common* divisors $\,d,\,$ hence the same *greatest* common divisor $(= \max S).$